# Check if someone is already Editing an Entry

Tags: ee3, entries, admin, author

I want to check if another author is alredy editing an entry in expressionengine backend. If yes i want to warn him that someone is already editing.

Is this possible somehow? I googled but wasn't able to find what i am searching for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, ExpressionEngine does not do entry locking out of the box. Most likely you will need an extension to enable this behavior. I used to have one back in the days of EE1, but I haven't had a need for it since then.

If you are on EE2, there is an extension on devot:ee called [Lock Entry](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/lock-entry) that might work for you.  I have not used it, but other users seem to have success with it.  Just be sure to read the comments and follow up with the forked and updated versions to fit your environment.

Comment: i'm on ee3. but thanks i will take a look at this addon :)